# How to Apply Bootstrap Labels design to database values displayed in status column of html table

Tags: jquery, html

```
function ShowData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Stock_Entry.aspx/ShowStockData",
    //parameter is not available so we dont need data
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var $table = "<table id='tblStockData' width='100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>";
        var header = "<thead><tr><th style='text-align:center;'>S.No</th><th>Shipment</th><th>Chassis No</th><th>Engine No</th><th>Status</th><th></th></tr></thead>";
        $table += header;
        var count = 1;
        //data.d is returning list of years
        //i =index, x element or data
        $.each(data.d, function (i, x) {

            var Om = ConvertDate(x.OrderMonth);
            var ArM = ConvertDate(x.ArrivalDate);
            var PayM = ConvertDate(x.PaymentDate);

            var row = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'>" + count + "</td>" +
            "<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.Shipment + "</span></td>" +
            "<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.ChassisNo + "</span></td>" +
            "<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.EngineNo + "</span></td>" +
            "<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.Status + "</span></td>" +
                "<td width='120px'>" + (x.Edit == false ? "" : "<a class='btn-sm btn-warning edit' onclick='EditDetail(this)' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>") + ' ' +
                  (x.Detail == false ? "" : "<a class='btn-sm btn-info edit' onclick='ViewDetail(this)' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window'></span></a>") + ' ' +
                (x.Delete == false ? "" : "<a class='btn-sm btn-danger edit' onclick='Delete(this)' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>") + "<span style='display:none'>" + x.No + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.Shipment + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.VehicleTypeID + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.TypeTitle + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ModelID + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ModelTitle + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + Om + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ArrQty + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.VehicleCondition + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ReceivingPlace + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + ArM + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.Duty + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ChassisNo + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.EngineNo + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.KeyNo + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.Color + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ColorTitle + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.CountryOfOrigin + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.CountryTitle + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.RefNumber + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.Status + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.ReceivingRoot + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + x.RootTitle + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + PayM + "</span></td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $table += row;
            count++;
        });

        $('#divStock').html($table);
        $table += "</table>";


        $('#tblStockData').DataTable({ "bPaginate": true, "bLengthChange": true, "bFilter": true, "bSort": true, "bInfo": true, "bAutoWidth": true, 'iDisplayLength': 3, "aLengthMenu": [[3, 5, 25, -1], [3, 5, 10, "All Items"]], "aaSorting": [],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "type": "numeric",
                "targets": 0
            }]
        });
        $('#divStock').show();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
  });
}
```

How to apply bootstrap labels design to database values displayed in HTML table. I want the field which has the value `sold` to `label label-danger` and `Available` to `label label-success`

This is the sample I have attached I want same. I want the Status column in HTML table to assign the bootstrap class according to their values

[image]

```
<div id="StockDetailDialog" class="StockDetailDialog" title="" style="display: none;
    text-align: center; vertical-align: central;">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong id="CustomerMsgTitle" align="center">Stock Detail Detail</strong>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="divStock" class="DivSize">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By checking the ajax x.Status return, you assign the class you want the table row, so you will have the result you need.

```
...
var row = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'>" + count + "</td>" +
"<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.Shipment + "</span></td>" +
"<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.ChassisNo + "</span></td>" +
"<td style='text-align:left;'><span>" + x.EngineNo + "</span></td>" +
if(x.Status == "Sold"){
    "<td style='text-align:left;'><span class='text-danger'>" + x.Status + "</span></td>"
}
else if(x.Status == "Avaliable"){
    "<td style='text-align:left;'><span class='text-success'>" + x.Status + "</span></td>"
} + ...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit the answer.